# QT - Saving Lower Resolution QPixmap

Tags: qt, qpixmap

Im Looking to lower the Resolution of Qpixmap cropped that is then saved a png

```
   QPixmap original(imgPath); // read in the image that was selected from tree
   QPixmap cropped = original.copy(cropRectInt); // make copy of image that is cropped to the size of the rect

//***Convert cropped to lower res here***//

   QFile file("5.png");
   cropped.save(&file, "PNG"); // save for testing

   QByteArray byteArray;
   QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
   cropped.save(&buffer, "PNG"); 
   QString imgBase64 = QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data());
```

Comment: What question are you asking? Are you receiving an error? If so, please add the error to the question.

Comment: could you elaborate about the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I have been searching for ways to lower the resolution of a Qpixmap without any luck,
the main aim is to just reduce the image size

Comment: The [QPixmap::scaled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-2) function allows you to change the size of the image.

Comment: I didn't think of using that to reduce the amount of data, was thinking of it in a to complicated way. will use something like 'cropped.scaledToHeight(100,Qt::FastTransformation)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `quality` parameter in call `QPixmap::save(QIODevice* device, const char* format, int quality)`

You can refer [this QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save-2)

Comment: This was more what I was looking for thanks have changed the save to `cropped.save(&file, "PNG", 50);`

Comment: after testing the best method was to use both the 'cropped.scaledToHeight' and the 'cropped.save( , , int quality)'